# Facebook Action "Watch This TV Show (insecure)"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can't find an answer to this anywhere, so here goes nothing

Have built an video Facebook app that publish opengraph actions when users watch tv_shows. Everything works fine, Actions is getting published, Videos can be streamed inline Facebook and users can add videos to there collection ( Watch later etc )

User can click tv_show name and they will come to the app, They can click app name and come to app.

But then it also shows **Watch this TV Show (insecure)** if clicked it will show a long error.

See this 2 screenshots for better understanding

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/v4kb/a4nx

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/v4kb/ec2b

Everything is delivered from secure connections so am puzzled and i can't find any answer to this.

Anyone ?

Comment: What are the links in question?

Comment: What are the **links** in question that are **insecure**. I cannot click a screenshot.

Comment: That's what am want to know also, There is no insecure links and i can't find any clue where to find the source of this.

Comment: Let me re-phrase, that image in your first screenshot link, there is a *Watch this TV Show (insecure)* that leads to a link, does it not? Could you include *that link* in this question whether you think it is insecure or not?

Comment: I can't extract any link from it, Check screenshot no.2 to see what happens when i click it. 

It feels like it's something that should not be there, Everything is secure, I mean users can play video inline on facebook, Can click to the app, click to the clip and save clip to watch later or watched

The only thing i can come up with is that it's a bug trigged becouse my video server is on a diffrent url that is not in my app domains ( can't add url not used, and it would not be an issue, FB plays this inline on feed even delivered from this url )

Comment: Here is link, Found it now

ajaxify="https://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink?action_ids=%5B570699992986501%5D"